# RegEx: Remove all content until first third special character

Tags: python, regex

I‘m trying to remove all content from a string until the first third slash using Python.

```
This/is/a/simple/test
```

Should be

```
simple/test
```

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ + Why do you need regex when you can `split('/')` and slice?

Comment: "first third"? Can there be multiple thirds?

Comment: And I downvoted because they didn't show us what solution(s) they tried. Zero effort on their part.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the re.sub() function to replace the parts of the string before the third slash with an empty string.

```
import re
string = "This/is/a/simple/test"
new_string = re.sub(r'^(?:[^/]*/){3}', '', string)
print(new_string)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why use RegEx, when you could just split the string, index it, then join it together.

```py
string = "This/is/a/simple/test"
new_string = "/".join(string.split("/")[3:])
print(new_string)
```

`"/".join(list)` is a function that joins a list into a function.

A functional representation of this would look something like:

```py
def list_join(_list, sep=""):
    string = ""
    for e in _list:
        string = string + sep + e
    return string
```

Using `[3:]` to slice the list and remove the first three elements, we get the expected result.